# Administer postgres from PGAdmin on remote mac using ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, osx-mountain-lion, ubuntu-12.04, pgadmin

I've got PostgreSQL installed on a Ubuntu server and I'm trying to connect to that server using PGAdmin on a remote macbook.

I've created an ssh tunnel -

```
macbook:~postgres$ ssh -L 5423:localhost:5432 postgres@mydomain.com
```

And I can connect using psql on the macbook as expected -

```
macbook:~ me$ psql -U postgres -p 5423 -h localhost
...
postgres=#
```

In the 'New Server Registration' window on PGAdminIII I'm entering the following credentials

```
Name - MyServer
Host - localhost
Port - 5423
Maintenance DB - postgres
Username - postgres
Password - <remote_postgres_password>
```

However the connection fails -

```
Error connecting to the server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Not sure what's going on here, these seem to be the same credentials I've used for psql.

Answer (score 0):

In your server, choose `md5` as password authentication on `pg_hba.conf` file. For example:

```
host all all 12.34.67.89 255.255.255.255 md5
```

While `12.34.67.89` is your remote ip. I'm facing the same problem last week. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Maulana. I already have that line (except that I've got 127.0.0.1/32 as my host address because I'm using the tunnel).